# Using Spinner selection as a value in Android

Tags: android, spinner

I am trying to get a Spinner to work in Android. It displays fine and I can select any one of the options in the list. But how do I transfer that to a string?
I would have thought in the code below that 'selected' would hold the selected string, but I get an 'Illegal modifier for the local class YourItemSelectedListener; only abstract or final is permitted' error on the 'YourItemSelectedListener'.
What am I doing wrong?
Many thanks for any help.

```
Spinner spinnerFPS = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_FPS);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.framesps, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerFPS.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinnerFPS.setOnItemSelectedListener(new YourItemSelectedListener());


        public class YourItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
                String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
                // Do nothing.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using an array resource for spinner create a resource handle
with local array declaration with `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.framesps);`

and then use that handle to access the selected item using position variable:

```
items[pos]
```

Heres a code edit:

```
Spinner spinnerFPS = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_FPS);
    String[] items=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.framesps);//handle to your arrays
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinnerFPS.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinnerFPS.setOnItemSelectedListener(new YourItemSelectedListener());


    public class YourItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            String selected =items[pos]; // use handler to access select item
        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that and now get the following error on 'createFromResource':  
The method createFromResource(Context, int, int) in the type ArrayAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (TCCalc, String[], int)

I am also getting: 
'YourItemSelectedListener cannot be resolved to a type'

and lastly on items[pos] I get:
Cannot refer to a non-final variable items inside an inner class defined in a different method.
I need to see a working demonstration of the Spinner to help me get my head around what's going on. Is there a real simple example out there? Cheers.

Comment: I hope that worked out, you can always check out code from google docs website

Comment: The problem with this is that the first item is automatically selected, and repeatedly selecting it will NOT fire the event. There is no way to set the spinner to a -1 index to prevent the first item from being selected, making it effectively useless for this type of application. It would be a VERY simple task for the android coders to fix this.

Comment: try setting the adapter first and then the listener

Answer (score 3):

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, items, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

You will have to add the `CurrentActivityName.this`. This will fix the issue. You just can't pass the argument context as `this`. You will have to put `ActivityName.this`.